# Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на страничку выводилось значение, которое в dropDownList?

Tags: php, javascript, yii2

Как сделать, чтобы при переходе на страничку выводилось значение, которое в dropDownList 
То есть, вот при переходе на страницу мы видим[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда в dropDownList меняем значение, то прибавляется нужное поле [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

или

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот вопрос, как сделать так, чтобы 
нужное поле было сразу при переходе на страничку

Вот таким кодом формируем - поле выбора, текстовое поле, поле загрузки

```
 <?   $list =  $form->field($model, 'type')->dropDownList([
    'string' => 'string',
    'image' => 'image',
],
    ['class' => 'js-type']);
?>
<?= $list ?>

<div id="string" style="display:none;">
    <?= $value; ?>
</div>

<div id="image" style="display:none;">
    <?= $file; ?>
</div>
```

Вот такой код скрипта js

```
$script = <<< JS
$('.js-type').on('change',function(){
var selection = $(this).val();
switch(selection){
 case "string":
$("#string").show()
$("#image").hide()
break;
 case "image":
$("#image").show()
$("#string").hide()
break;
}
```

Comment: А что значит нужное?

Comment: Значение в поле Type, которое возвращает dropDownList (string or image)

Comment: Ну у Вас что то должно по умолчанию быть. Или должны храниться предыдущие значения?